# Libraries and dependencies in C++ Ubuntu

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Hi recently i got invited to a school project, for that i installed WSM with ubuntu on my computer, after that i git cloned the project and tried to build it with cmake, the problem occurs after i try to make, libraries that should be included in c++ packages that i already installed are always missing, some of those libraries are: vector; algorithm; ETC.
The type of errors that i get are:

```
/home/bruno/projetos/MISEN/ImageSearch/src/rbisen/SseIee.cpp:4:10: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
4 | #include <algorithm>
```

The same errors occurs with vector and a bunch of other libraries.
What could i be missing in my instalation that is causing this problem.
Thanks in advance

CMAKE:

```
# sgx vars
if (NOT DEFINED ENV{SGX_SDK})
    set(SGX_SDK "/opt/intel/sgxsdk")
else()
    set(SGX_SDK $ENV{SGX_SDK})
endif ()

# include paths for the sgx versions of standard libs
set(SGX_INCLUDE_PATHS ${SGX_SDK}/include ${SGX_SDK}/include/libcxx ${SGX_SDK}/include/tlibc)

# flags
set(DEBUG_FLAGS "-g -O0")
if (SIMULATED_MODE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${DEBUG_FLAGS} -Wno-pointer-arith -c -Wall -fPIC -Wall -m64 -fvisibility=hidden -fpie -fstack-protector")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${DEBUG_FLAGS} -Wno-pointer-arith -c -Wall -fPIC -Wall -m64 -fvisibility=hidden -fpie -fstack-protector -fno-builtin-function -nostdinc++")
endif ()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(KMEANS_DIR ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/training/seq-kmeans)

# sources
set(KMEANS_SRCS ${KMEANS_DIR}/kmeans.cpp)
set(UTIL_SRCS ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/parallel.cpp ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/scoring.cpp ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/img_processing.cpp ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/util.cpp ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/training/lsh/lsh.cpp)

# define target library
add_library(${EXTERN_LIB_NAME}
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen/util/IeeUtils.cpp ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen/util/vec_int.cpp ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen/util/vec_token.cpp
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen/QueryEvaluator.cpp ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen/SseIee.cpp
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/trusted.cpp
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/untrusted.cpp
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/training.cpp
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/repository.cpp
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/training/bagofwords.cpp
        ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/training/util.cpp
        ${UTIL_SRCS} ${KMEANS_SRCS})

if (SIMULATED_MODE)
    target_link_libraries(${EXTERN_LIB_NAME} trusted_util)
else()
    target_link_libraries(${EXTERN_LIB_NAME})
endif ()

if (SIMULATED_MODE)
    target_include_directories(${EXTERN_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE ${EXTERN_DIR} ${EXTERN_DIR}/src ${KMEANS_DIR} ${FRAMEWORK_INCLUDE_DIR} ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen/util)
else()
    target_include_directories(${EXTERN_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE ${EXTERN_DIR} ${EXTERN_DIR}/src ${KMEANS_DIR} ${FRAMEWORK_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SGX_INCLUDE_PATHS} ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen ${EXTERN_DIR}/src/rbisen/util)
endif ()
```

This is the cmake relative to this part of the project

Comment: Remove `-c` option from the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` assignment. CMake automatically uses this option when compile a source. As for `-nostdinc++` option, it disables searching in directories which contains standard C++ headers. Exactly this option causes your error message (absence of `algorithm` header).

Comment: `-fPIC` probably not the issue here, but you can make this option compiler independent by setting the `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` target property to `True`

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot that actually worked, do you have any idea why my professor would do this? Or could this be an error that he didnt  face or something?

Comment: The comment for `SGX_INCLUDE_PATHS` variable suggest that it should contain directories with "sgx" variant of C++ headers. But it seems that something goes wrong.

Comment: I'm the original author of that library. As an advice, the SGX SDK libraries for C++ were a bit unstable, and that code is from 2018, so it can be a bit outdated. If you run into more problems I'd suggest you try and run the code in a Ubuntu 16.04 with the SGX SDK from around the Summer of 2018...

Comment: @GuilhermeBorges Thanks a lot, i didn't see the this message at the time and i talked to professor Bernardo and he explained a bit of how the SGX worked and why the flag was used